# Delete Oracle Change Notifications

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I'm trying to deregister change notifications in Oracle 12c by executing:

```
DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.DEREGISTER(24906);
```

But this gives an error:

> ORA-29970: Specified registration id does not exist

Although when I query the `USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS` view it does clearly state the correct `regid`.

Any one encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Doc ID 971412.1)**

**How Can Database Change Notifications Not Created With PL/SQL Be Removed?**

[ *Last updated on JULY 05, 2017* ]

> Applies to:

Oracle Database - Enterprise Edition - Version `10.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.2` [Release `10.2 to 11.2`]

Oracle Data Provider for .NET - Version `10.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.1` [Release `10.2 to 11.2`]

Information in this document applies to any platform.
***Checked for relevance on 14th Dec 2016***

> Symptoms

You have an application that creates database change notifications via the `OCI API` or `a higher level API` that exposes this functionality such as `ODP.Net`.  It does not create the notifications via `PL/SQL`, `either through a stored procedure or PL/SQL block`.

This application exits without cleaning up those notifications, typically via a fatal error as any controlled shutdown should remove any notifications.  Or it may be that the application is still in development and the code to remove the notifications has a bug, or hasn't been added yet.

This leaves orphaned notifications in the database, which cannot be removed because they can only be removed within the same session in which they were created.  Neither can they be removed with `the PL/SQL function` `DBMS_CQ_NOTIFICATION.DEREGISTER();` this throws the error:

> ORA-29970: Specified registration id does not exist.

Comment: This explains a lot. But what is the solution to this then? The registration is indeed triggered from a .NET service, but I need to be able to delete it through PL/SQL

Answer (score 2):

Solution according to the MOS-Note:

- Use patched Oracle version (bug fix included in 12.1 or later and the 11.2.0.4 Database and Client patchset)
- enable following event to consume the fix: event "10865 trace name context forever, level 1".